# codeigniter array values insert product_id

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, insert

Am trying to insert `array` in database using `codeigniter`. But i got a error like

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2, 3) VALUES ('5', '6', '11', '13')' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (0, 1, 2, 3) VALUES ('5', '6', '11', '13')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/hari/billing-system/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

**Controller:**

```
class Customer_order extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('orders');
    }
    
    function addnewcustomerorder()
    {
        $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
        $data = array(
            'product_id' => $product_id
            );
        //print_r($data);
        $res = $this->orders->addnewcustomerorder($data);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
function addnewcustomerorder($data)
{
    if($data['product_id']!="") 
    {
        foreach($data as $a)
        {
            $res=$this->db->insert('customer_orders',$a);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like to insert the values in `database` like this
[image]

> Note: ignore `customer_id`

How can i `insert` the values in database

Answer (score 0):

It helps to name variables what they are, since $data['product_id'] is an array of ids it should be made plural ($data['product_ids']), this would have helped debugging your code

```
 //since product_id is an array of product ids (should change it to $data['product_ids']) 
/*$data = [
        'product_id' => [2,3,4,6,7]
        ];  
*/
//var_dump($data); showing values like array(1) { ["product_id"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(2) "13" } } i pass only product_id 
function addnewcustomerorder($data)
{
  $orders = [];
  foreach($data['product_id'] as $product_id){

     if($product_id AND $product_id != "") 
      {

         $this->db->insert('customer_orders',['product_id'=>$product_id]);
         $orders[] =  $this->db->insert_id();

     }
  }
  return $orders;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro showing error `Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (`product_id`) VALUES (Array)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/hari/billing-system/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

Comment: var_dump($data); showing values like `array(1) { ["product_id"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(2) "13" } }`  i pass only `product_id`

Comment: you need to do foreach($data['product_id'] as product_id)

Comment: check what i added.

Comment: Oh god again error `INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (5) VALUES ('')`

Comment: $this->db->insert('customer_orders',['product_id'=>$product_id]);

Answer (score 0):

First of all using forech on database query is not advisory. 
Codeigniter have [insert_batch](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) function to add multiple row to the database. You should use that.

Now coming to your problem, From reference to your comment if this is the array you are trying to insert:

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )

)
```

Then this is the code which may helps you.

Your Controller:

```
function addnewcustomerorder()
{
    $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');        
    $res = $this->orders->addnewcustomerorder($product_id);
}
```

Your Model:

```
function addnewcustomerorder($product_id)
{
    if($data['product_id']!="") 
    {
        $your_product_array = ''; 

        foreach($product_id as $pro_id)
        {
            $your_product_array[] = array('product_id'=>$pro_id);                       
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('customer_orders',$your_product_array);
        // This above code inser all the row at once. 
        // I am suggesting to use database transaction.
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For Information: Here is the array structure of `your_product_array`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
        )

)
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

change your model to this
Assuming that your `order_id` is autoincrement and `customer_id` will be empty or null (because you neer send that value)

```
function addnewcustomerorder($data){
    if($data['product_id']!="") {
        foreach($data as $a){
            $res=$this->db->insert('customer_orders', array('product_id' => $a));
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sorry showing error `Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (`product_id`) VALUES (Array)`

Comment: ok, set it to `$data = array('customer_id' => NULL, 'product_id' => $a); $this->db->insert('customer_orders', $data);`

Comment: You mean inside `foreach`

Comment: You don't need a foreach loop since you are inserting one data row

Comment: Bro again error Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (`customer_id`, `product_id`) VALUES (NULL, Array)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/hari/billing-system/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691